# Как засечь, что button была нажата два раза подряд?

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Недавно начал изучать Windows Form, пытаюсь перевести свой консольный калькулятор в Windows Form. Хотел реализовать следующее, если user нажимает два раза на btn_minus, я меняю два минуса в TextBox'e на "+". Пытался реализовать это дело, но пока без успешно.

```
public partial class CalcForm : Form
{        
    public CalcForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {               
        textBox1.Text += "-";
    }

   private void btn_minus_DoubleClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {           
       textBox1.Text = "+";
   }
```

Ну как то так, рылся в msdn'e, там в заметках написано, что разряды стилей ControlStyles.StandardClick и ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick заданы в значение false для элемента управления Button, при этом не создается событие DoubleClick. Может быть, поэтому не срабатывает...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DoubleClick` не подходит, потому что пользователь может нажать 2 раза с разницей по времени выше, чем заложена для двойного клика

```
private void btn_minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.EndsWith("-"))
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1) + "+";
    }
    else textBox1.Text += "-";
}
```